# Why does a green glass block more UVA/B rays than a blue one?

Tags: electromagnetism

Why does a green glass block more UVA/B rays than a blue one?

White glass blocks 36%, blu 43% and green glass blocks most UVA rays. That is why beer and olive oil bottles are green, they say.

Edit: [here](http://www.aromadictionary.com/EVOO_blog/?p=357) I found a graph plotting green and blue tinted glass:

[image: Glass absorption]

Probably, as John says, green is over-extimated, but the fact still remains that *green is more effective than blue*, (probably amber more than both).

Why so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim that green glass is used because it absorbs uv light seems to be something of a myth. Some Googling found me this spectrum of clear, green and amber glass:

[image: Glass spectrum]

The article I got this from can be [found in this PDF](https://gravitywinehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/Glass-Wine-bottles-and-UV-light.pdf).

Green glass doesn't do that much better than clear glass, and if light absorption were really that important all bottles would be amber.

The colour of glass originates from transition metal ions. The green colour is normally achieved using chromium, and the blue colour using cobalt (annoyingly I can't find any spectra of chromium glass and cobalt glass online). The colours of the first row transition metal complexes are caused by ligand field splitting of the $3d$ orbitals. I think it would be very difficult to predict why cobalt and chromium absorb at the wavelengths they do.

Comment: I took those data from [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19614895)

Comment: Indeed since rubies' red also comes from chromium impurities, environment probably plays a very large role in how it acts.

Comment: @bobie: That paper is behind a paywall. Can you extract the most relevant spectra from it?

Comment: @bobie: If you're asking why cobalt ions absorb less than chromium in a glass matrix then there isn't a simple answer for that other than they have different electronic structures so they absorb at diffrent wavelengths.

Comment: The link to the article seems dead now. [Archived here.](https://web.archive.org/web/20200926010316/http://www.wrap.org.uk/sites/files/wrap/Glass%20Wine%20bottles%20and%20UV%20light.pdf)

Comment: @Urb thanks, I found a copy on another web site.

Comment: Thanks for updating it.